# Pooled panel regression with group-wise clustering by time

Tags: r, regression, clustering, python, robust-standard-error

How can I compute t-statistics for the coefficients of the pooled panel regression model below such that I account for group-wise clustering by time?

$$
Y_{it} = \alpha + \beta x_{it} + \epsilon_{it}
$$

I've read through several textbooks, but haven't found a simple explanation.

If anybody could also advise on how to fit this model using Python or R, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks for any help!